# Ionic Playlist navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to Ionic and I need help with navigation. I started the project using the sidemenus starter template. It is a simple barebones template that lists items in a playlist using a playlist control. But, now I'm stuck! How do I allow the user to navigate to a unique page for each item in the list. What is the full process?

Do I first add a new state in app.js or can I simply make a new folder and add a new html file? And then do where do I place the path to navigate to the new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write states in app.js then give state url on playlist.html on click it takes you to the new html page what have mentioned in states templateUrl.

Comment: How do you add multiple state url's to ensure that the new page reflects the list item that was clicked?